# Tableau Query: Year-end week rolling

Tags: sql, tableau-api, week-number

In Tableau, I am making a report which shows data according to the current week for 4 weeks in the future. I take a snapshot of the data from SQL Server every week on Monday and upload the result of the query through an Excel file onto Tableau. I have the following columns with me- [Year], [Target Week], [Snapshot Year], [Snapshot Week] and other miscellaneous data fields in the excel file.

Currently, I have set a Calculated Field in Tableau to lock the data 4 weeks into the future from the current week, i.e., [Snapshot Week]. This way, as we move on to the next week for a snapshot, the data will be 4 weeks in the future relatively for that week.

Calculated Field:
IIF([Target Week]=([Snapshot Week] + 3), 'Locked', 'Not Locked')

Now, since it is year end, and the current snapshot week is 51, the above logic will give [Week] as 54. How do I modify it to return the 1st week of 2015, so as to lock the data for that week in the future?

Edit 1:
I have used the following IF formula, and the ones that are coming as TRUE in the Formula column is the one I want. But, week 49 onwards the formula doesn't work.

IF(B2=A2+4, TRUE, FALSE)

Snapshot Week   Target Week   Qty   Formula
47              51            533   TRUE
47              50            234   FALSE
47              49            252   FALSE
48              52            345   TRUE
48              51            344   FALSE
48              50            475   FALSE
49              53             75   TRUE
49              52            354   FALSE
49              51            242   FALSE
50               1            231   FALSE
50              53            214   FALSE
50              52            197   FALSE
51               2            180   FALSE
51               1            163   FALSE
51              53            146   FALSE
52               3            129   FALSE
52               2            112   FALSE
52               1             94   FALSE

Comment: Did you check, whether "MODULO" ( `%` in TSQL) serves your purpose?

Comment: I have been suggested the same, but I am not sure how I can integrate MODULO into the query to make it work throughout the year if the number of weeks are different for a year. This year the number of weeks are 53, but some year in the future might have the number of weeks as 52.

Comment: If your database (version) does not provide a generic way to calculate the number of weeks in a specific year, you might want to fill an auxiliary table with the respective values.